# SUM(table2.value * table2.value) (+ table1.value) in a view

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following view in a search engine:

```
CREATE VIEW msr_joined_view AS 
SELECT table1.id AS msr_id, table1.msr_number, table1.overview, 
SUM(table2.quantity * table2.unit_price) AS grand_total 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.msr_id 
GROUP BY table1.msr_number;
```

Which gets me output like this:

```
msr_id    msr_number    overview    grand_total
------    ----------    ---------   -----------
 1          4            stuff       100.00
 2          5            other       15.00
 3          7            more        17.95
```

I now need to bring in a column called `taxes_shipping`, which exists in table1. I need to add the value of that column to grand_total for each row. How can I modify my view to do this?

Table structures:

```
table1   has many  table2
------             ------ 
  id                msr_id(FK)
  msr_number        unit_price
  overview          quantity
  taxes_shipping
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another column into `SELECT`, e.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW msr_joined_view AS 
SELECT table1.id AS msr_id, table1.msr_number, table1.overview, 
SUM(table2.quantity * table2.unit_price) + (SELECT SUM(taxes_shipping) FROM table1 t1 WHERE id = table1.id) 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.msr_id 
GROUP BY table1.msr_number;
```

Comment: Almost. Eliminating line 3, moving `as_grand_total` to the next line and adding table1.taxes_shipping instead of the SELECT statement got me what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris I thought you still needed `grand_total`. Removed the 3rd line. However, I would still recommend using inner query as `GROUP BY ` does not guarantee matching values for non grouped columns unless all the columns are added into `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Yeah, apologies, I spoke too soon. I need to add `taxes_shipping` to the result of `table2.unit_price * table2.quantity`, and make the result of that `grand_total`. When I tried your setup, I didn't get that result. I'll try again. Might have fat fingered it.

Comment: @Chris cool, let me know if you are still not getting the required output